# Ошибка telebot. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я начинающий в `Python`, сейчас изучаю телеграмм-ботов. Захотел сделать как первый мини-проект текстовую игру в телеграмме.

***Код:***

```py
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    arthp = 28
    witchhp = 20
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, напиши /startgame, чтобы начать")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "/startgame - начать игру")
    elif message.text == "/startgame":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Добро пожаловать в игру! Твой герой сейчас - КиберРыцарь 1 уровня. HP: 20, Урон: 3-6 единиц.")
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Твой первый противник - КиберБомж. HP: 10, Урон: 2-4 единицы.")
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Твой ход первый! Сейчас ты можешь только бить или использовать свое особое умение: восстановление здоровья на 1-5 единиц.")
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Атака или Перк")
    elif message.text == "Атака":
        witchdm = random.randrange(3, 6)
        arthp -= witchdm
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты нанес ", witchdm, " единиц урона КиберБомжу. КиберБомж HP: ", arthp)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ход КиберБомжа!")
        artdm = random.randrange(2, 6)
        witchhp -= artdm
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Кибербомж нанес тебе ", artdm, " урона. Твой HP: ", witchhp)
    elif message.text == "Перк":
        heal = random.randrange(3, 11)
        witchhp += heal
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты похилил себя на ", heal, ". Твой HP: ", witchhp)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ход КиберБомжа!")
        artdm = random.randrange(2, 10)
        witchhp -= artdm
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "КиберБомж нанес тебе  ", artdm, " единиц урона. Твой HP: ", witchhp)
    if arthp <= 0:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты победил! Мои поздравления, пока это все, игра в разработке")
    if witchhp <= 0:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты погиб! RIP :(")


bot.polling( none_stop = True )
```

Появляется неизвестная и непонятная для меня ошибка:

```py
2020-04-25 21:38:37,891 (util.py:65 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: object expected as reply markup"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "textgamebot.py", line 23, in get_text_messages
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты нанес ", witchdm, " единиц урона КиберБомжу. КиберБомж HP: ", arthp)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 598, in send_message
    reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification))
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 140, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
    return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
    raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: object expected as reply markup"}']
"
2020-04-25 21:38:37,894 (__init__.py:417 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: object expected as reply markup"}']"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове функции запятыми отделяются позиционные аргументы. Вам требуется сформировать строку перед её передачей в функцию.

***Пример:***

```py
text = f'Ты нанес {witchdm} единиц урона КиберБомжу. КиберБомж HP: {arthp}'
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)
```